# screen garbled after suspend when not using unity

Tags: unity, i3-wm

When using unity or gnome my laptop wakes up from suspend and everything works properly.

When using i3, the laptop wakes up from suspend but the screen is garbled, and I need to reboot, not even a lightdm restart helps.

I am using `unity-settings-daemon`, should I start another process that fixes this and is already running in unity?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't specify any hardware types. If you are using Intel graphics, it might be [Bug #1452318](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1452318)

Comment: Hi Matthew, and welcome to askubuntu! When an answer essentially consists of a link to an external website, it is encouraged to at least briefly summarize the contents of that link, as links may break. Here, I see a different problem. The question is more than five years old! I doubt the (very recent) bug report applies here.